# Transpose a NxN matrix

Tags: java, math, matrix

I have a NxN matrix and it trying to transpose it by this code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < mat_size; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat_size; ++j) {
            double tmpJI = get(j, i);
            put(j, i, get(i, j));
            put(i, j, tmpJI);
        }
    }
```

it doesn't work, what is the problem? thanks in advance.

Comment: can you also add the implementation of "get(j,i)" & "put(i,j,tmp)" methods.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea what is wrong with the question?

Comment: @AliAlamiri : No critical code(get, put methods), it doesn't work without trying to solve ... it was enough to debug 2 minutes to solve the problem.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea I'm sure if the OP had put the code for the two methods someone would've told him wrong for putting too much code in a question ... And as usual he'll get pointed to SSCCE.

Comment: I didn't add put and get because it's a compicated matrix type (I forgot its name) so it wouldn't help you .. and as the comments said the problem is the index j stopped at

Comment: Every answer uses pre-increment, but that cannot be correct for a zero-based matrix, can it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't work since you're swapping the whole matrix with itself. What you need to do is exchange the upper triangle with the lower one:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
```

is one way.

Comment: Need to refresh what i've leart in linear algebra  .. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Going from 0 to mat_size will get you reorder the whole matrix two times, getting the original one again.

change to :

```
for(int i = 0; i < mat_size; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        double tmpJI = get(j, i);
        put(j, i, get(i, j));
        put(i, j, tmpJI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap only if j > i. So the inner loop must start at i+1. For j==i (the center diagonal) no swapping is needed, too.

Your solution doesn't work because you're actually swapping twice (once with j=x and i=y and once with j=y and i=x.

Answer (score 0):

For example the (2,5) is swapped for i=2,j=5 and i=5,j=2. Swap twice does nothing.

```
for(int i = 0; i < mat_size; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        double tmpJI = get(j, i);
        put(j, i, get(i, j));
        put(i, j, tmpJI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the elements that you swap in the lower triangle of the matrix gets swapped again when the iteration reaches the other side of the diagonal. That is the element is swapped twice which results in nothing.
Try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mat_size; ++i) {
for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
    double tmpJI = get(j, i);
    put(j, i, get(i, j));
    put(i, j, tmpJI);
  }
}
```